# Defining a named function type that returns any type

Tags: function, go, generics

I would like to define a function type (what we call delegate in C#) whose return value can be anything (is unknown at compile type) and after reading Go docs I found that the current version of the language does not support generics.

After searching StackOverflow I came across a post suggesting that the return type can be set as `interface{}` which implies that any type can be returned by that function. Then I wrote the following code to test how it works:

```
type Consumer func() interface {}

func TestConsumer() Consumer {
    return func() string {
         return "ok"
    }
}
```

But I got the following error

> cannot use func literal (type func() string) as type Consumer in return argument

This is while when I change the return type of `Consumer` to `string`, it works without any problem.

The question is what is that I am doing wrong and how can I achieve writing a function type (delegate) that can return anything and assign an actual functions to that?

Comment: return a function whose return type is `interface{}` instead of `string`. e.g. `return func() interface{} { return "ok" }`.

Comment: @mkopriva: So the language cannot do implicit type conversions like we have in Java or C#, is that right?

Comment: The language *can* do implicit conversions. But `func() interface{}` and `func() string` are incompatible types and not convertible **even explicitly**.

Comment: You can read about [Type Conversion in the Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) to understand when one type can be converted to another.

Comment: wait for go v1.18 stable. there is a generic in there

Comment: @mkopriva: Ok, I was actually viewing `interface {}` as equivalent to `Object` that's why I was confused.

Comment: `interface{}` should be thought of less as a type, and more as an interface satisfied by all types. I wrote some [details about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813472/2081835) in the past. It is the underlying concrete type that makes all the difference.

Comment: `interface{}` doesn't mean "any type" it literally means just `interface{}` as `uint16` means `uint16`. Go is statically typed. `interface{}` is different from anything that is not `interface{}`.

Comment: OP is way too convoluted for a decently meaniingful and useful example, but you can always do something like this https://go.dev/play/p/gabvmMzCII4?v=gotip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the function type `func() string` does not conform to the function type `func() interface{}`.

The reason for this is because the function type `func() interface{}` means a function that explicitly returns a value of type `interface{}`, and while a `string` can be easily casted to an `interface{}`, the overall *function signatures* are **not** the same.

The correct code would be:

```
type Consumer func() interface {}

func TestConsumer() Consumer {
    return func() interface{} {
         return "ok"
    }
}
```

The string gets implicity casted to the `interface{}` type, and the function signatures are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use **Go 1.18**, use type parameters to define your own generic named function type. You can then use it in other generic functions and instantiate it with a type parameter, or instantiate it with concrete types when needed:

<sup>let's say that a function that **returns** `T` is called a "producer" though</sup>

```
type Producer[T any] func() T

// instantiate with concrete type
func TestProducer() Producer[string] {
    return func() string {
         return "ok"
    }
}

// instantiate with type parameter
func TestProducer[T any]() Producer[T] {
    return func() T {
        return *new(T)
    }
}
```

In the latter case, you'll have to instantiate `TestProducer` — the general rule being, at some point the type parameters must be known at compile time.

```
func main() {
    fn := TestProducer[string]()
    foo := fn()
    fmt.Println(foo) // foo is the empty string

    fn2 := TestProducer[uint64]()
    bar := fn2()
    fmt.Println(bar) // bar is 0
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/HDmgV_vu7MN

Answer (score 0):

```
func TestConsumer() interface{} {
    return func() string {
         return "ok"
    }
}
```

Please try with this one